# How to set up ServiceLocationProvider for unit testing navigation in Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, prism

A Prism/Unity application I'm working on has a view that is in charge of implementing the `GoBack()` and `GoForward()` methods of `RegionNavigationJournal`. This will be the first time I'll need to unit test anything that uses the RegionManager, and I'm running into an error advising that

> ServiceLocationProvider must be set

when I try to locate the region whose navigation is being controlled (which is a different region than the one the view in question belongs to).

Based on this I've done some digging and haven't come across anything about resolving the "ServiceLocationProvider" error in the context of Prism navigation. If possible I'd prefer avoiding mocking anything, but if that ends up being the only/best option it's not out of the question.

If there's more information I can include please let me know. Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: ServiceLocationProvider is configured as part of the boot sequence defined by Bootstrapper in ConfigureServiceLocator() method. Are you using Unity or MEF?

Comment: Create a basic Bootstrapper derived from UnityBootstrapper, it will have all you need to unit test.

Comment: I'm not sure where I'd start to do that. Do you happen to have any resources I could look into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did some more reading and found that `ServiceLocationProvider` is initiated as part of `Bootstrapper.Run()`. Had some issues creating the dummy bootstrapper since I wasn't sure how to implement `CreateShell`, but I realized that you can just return a new `DependencyObject`.

Here's what my test bootstrapper looks like:

```
 public class TestBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return new DependencyObject();
    }
}
```

The following needs to be done at the beginning of the test to get a region added:

```
TestBootstrapper bootstrapper = new TestBootstrapper();
bootstrapper.Run();

this.RegionManager = new RegionManager();
this.RegionManager.Regions.Add(UIRegionNames.ContextResultsPane, new Region());
```

In the constructor for the ViewModel that's being tested, I do the following to get an instance of the navigation service journal:

```
public NavigationContextControlViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    IRegionNavigationService navigationService;

    this.RegionManager = regionManager;
    navigationService = this.RegionManager.Regions[UIRegionNames.ContextResultsPane].NavigationService;
    navigationService.Navigated += CheckIfNavigateCanExecuteHasChanged;
    this.ContextResultsNavigationJournal = navigationService.Journal;
}
```